# Using ViewDiscovery in Prism to construct a simple menu structure

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm trying to break down my `MenuItems` into separate views so my app can be more manageable. My intent is to use view discovery to build the menu structure upon initialization. My File menu resides in `Menu1Region` and my Edit menu resides in `Menu2Region`. When I run the app, the File and Edit menus do not drop down and the headers have lots of spacing around them with a submenu arrow on the right side. Any help would be appreciated.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PrismDemo.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Height="350" Width="525" >    
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu>
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Menu1Region" />
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Menu2Region" />
        </Menu>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ModuleAModule.cs

```
using ModuleA.Views;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Modularity;
using Prism.Regions;

namespace ModuleA
{
    public class ModuleAModule : IModule
    {
        public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
        {
            IRegionManager _regionManager = containerProvider.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Menu1Region", typeof(ViewA));
            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("Menu2Region", typeof(ViewB));
        }

        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

ViewB.xaml

```
<MenuItem Header="Edit"
    x:Class="ModuleA.Views.ViewB"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <MenuItem Header="_Copy" />
    <MenuItem Header="P_aste" />
</MenuItem>
```

ViewA.xaml

```
<MenuItem Header="File"
    x:Class="ModuleA.Views.ViewA"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <MenuItem Header="Save" />
    <MenuItem Header="SaveAs" />
</MenuItem>
```

Comment: I'm wondering if I need a custom region adapter to display views in a menu?

Comment: I'm wondering whether it makes sense to put a `ContentControl` in a `Menu`?

Answer (score 0):

Although I originally wanted to define a `MenuItem` as a region, I decided to define a `Menu` as a region and use a `StackPanel`. There seems to be only one minor issue. When one menu is dropped down, moving the mouse over to an adjacent menu doesn't automatically drop down the adjacent menu and the user must click into it.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PrismDemo.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Height="350" Width="525" >    
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Menu1Region" />
            <ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="Menu2Region" />
        </StackPanel>        
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ViewA.xaml

```
<Menu
    x:Class="ModuleA.Views.ViewA"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <MenuItem Header="File">
        <MenuItem Header="Save" />
        <MenuItem Header="SaveAs" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

ViewB.xaml

```
<Menu
    x:Class="ModuleA.Views.ViewB"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
    prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <MenuItem Header="Edit">
        <MenuItem Header="_Copy" />
        <MenuItem Header="P_aste" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Menu` is an `ItemsControl` so including `ContentControl` is unnecessary. Below are the changes needed to the original post. Thanks goes out to Brian Lagunas for his help with this.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="PrismDemo.Views.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mi="clr-namespace:ModuleA.Views;assembly=ModuleA"   
        xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
        prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
        Height="350" Width="525" >    
    <Grid ShowGridLines="True">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Menu prism:RegionManager.RegionName="MenuRegion" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

ModuleAModule.cs

```
using ModuleA.Views;
using Prism.Ioc;
using Prism.Modularity;
using Prism.Regions;

namespace ModuleA
{
    public class ModuleAModule : IModule
    {
        public void OnInitialized(IContainerProvider containerProvider)
        {
            IRegionManager _regionManager = containerProvider.Resolve<IRegionManager>();
            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MenuRegion", typeof(ViewA));
            _regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("MenuRegion", typeof(ViewB));
        }

        public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry containerRegistry)
        {

        }
    }
}
```